# Is it possible to instruct GDB to get a variable value asynchronously from the target?

Tags: gdb

I achieved the `printf()` functionality by placing a breakpoint by assigning "print the variable value and then continue" code to it:

```
break main.c:18
commands
print myVar
cont
end
```

This worked fine so far. However, AFAIU, it requires many communications with the target (a microcontroller in my case):

1. Microcontroller sends a signal when a breakpoint is hit
2. GDB immediately asks for value of `myVar`
3. MCU sends `myVar` value
4. GDB instructs MCU to continue

Those steps cause a significant jitter so the application on the MCU behaves very odd.

Is there any chance to tell GDB to do above steps in one go, like: "Tell me the `myVar` value and then continue without waiting any further instructions."?

Comment: You may also want to check out the [dprintf](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dynamic-Printf.html) command as an alternative to break+commands.

Comment: @ssbssa `dprintf` function seems like what I achieved manually by combining `break + commands + printf + cont + end`. It causes the mentioned jitter and there is no way to tell the amount of jitter difference (it looks like the same).

Answer (score 1):

> AFAIU, it requires many communications with the target

There are actually *way more* packets exchanged between GDB and the target (GDB remote protocol is *very* chatty). You can see them with `set debug remote on`.

What you are looking for is [tracing](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Tracepoints.html#Set-Tracepoints):

```
> For each tracepoint, you can specify, in advance, some arbitrary set
> of data that you want the target to collect in the trace buffer when
> it hits that tracepoint. The collected data can include registers,
> local variables, or global data. Later, you can use GDB commands to
> examine the values these data had at the time the tracepoint was hit.
```

**Update:**

> When I issue `tstart`, GDB gives `error: Target does not support this command.`

Apparently you are using something other than `gdbserver` on the MCU (you didn't tell us what's on the remote end of GDB), and your remote end doesn't support tracing.

This could be an instance of `gdbserver` being too old, or it could be that the remote debugging stub doesn't implement this part of the protocol.

If it's the former, you may be able to update the `gdbserver` to newer version. If it's the latter, there isn't much you could do (except implementing tracing support yourself).

Comment: I didn't find a complete example, but here is what I did [using this document](https://suchakra.wordpress.com/2016/06/29/fast-tracing-with-gdb/): `trace`, `actions`, `collect myVar`,`end`. When I issue `tstart`, GDB gives error: `Target does not support this command.`

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink and it wouldn't surprise me that its gdb server implementation (st-util) has no tracing support. I'll check OpenOCD for that support. If none works I'll test a simple C application on my pc in order to verify and accept your answer.